# Configuring IPTables without connection tracking module

Tags: iptables, nf-conntrack

Usually connection tracking is required for outbound connections to allow established connections back in, for instance:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

I don't have connection tracking enabled on my server so I was wondering if there are any alternative rules or solution for this?

Comment: Create lots of stateless rules, like we did back in the ol' ipchains days.

Comment: You meant ctstate instead of state right ? How does it come you don't have connection tracking enabled ?

Comment: I meant `state` and I think both modules use the same kernel internals underneath, `ctstate` is just a newer implementation It's a OpenVZ hypervisor and connection tracing is disabled due to some permanence problems: https://bugzilla.openvz.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2755

Answer (score 2):

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -j ACCEPT` will allow any non-SYN TCP packets through. It doesn't give you RELATED (viz. connections allowed because of other connections, eg. ftp->ftp-data), nor does it drop connections that weren't properly ESTABLISHED, but linux won't do anything with it if it is unexpected -- it gets dropped to the floor. If you need UDP, you're in for some fun enumerating allowed connections.